# How to solve regression error when non-normalizing output

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having a simple regression problem using sequential models, where I usually normalized the input and output to get good results.

When I don't normalize the output, I get saturated output performance. Any idea what might be the issue?

I tried to change the output layer to linear,

`activation=tf.keras.activations.linear` or
`activation=tf.nn.relu` or
`activation=tf.nn.relu6`.

But the performance is still the same "saturated".
I also tried to remove the BatchNormalization layer
`tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()`
But no improvement.

Given that once I normalized the output, the output becomes very good.

```
modelF = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(SNN_Layers[0],activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape=(Act_Inputs.shape[1],), kernel_initializer='normal'),
                                             tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(SNN_Layers[1], activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer='normal'),
                                             tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
                                             tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(SNN_Layers[2], activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer='normal'),
                                             tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer='normal'),
                                             ])
```

I expect the output to converge in the "not normalized output case" in similar behavior as it converges in the "normalized output case".

Comment: relu will not work well if the output can be negative as relu is 0 when x<0 and equal to x everywhere else. For regression i would suggest using (which also seems to be most common) `activation=tf.keras.activations.linear` as the output activation, as it works great with negative numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

The most plausible reason here could be **initialisation**. When output is not normalized, the actual values may be very far from default initialised values, which can lead to gradients vanishing or exploding.

You can provide you custom initialization, such that its mean and variance is closer to your non-normlized output.

```
mu = <your mean>
stdd = <your std>
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=mu, stddev=std, seed=None))
```

There has been lot of research on this topic. You can go through [Glorot initializatio](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf)n paper to get more understanding